# Angular Kendo Grid using Typescript how to generate Dynamic columns using Pivot table style?

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, pivot, kendo-grid

I would to know how to generate dynamic columns in Angular 4 and above, Kendo Grid using typescript like pivot style.

I have tried using the Kendo Auto-Generated column examples provided in Telerik / Progress website.

Here is the sample examples provided by Kendo

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/auto-generated/

Expecting Pivot Style Kendo Grid

Comment: The link you shared shows how it works... It would help us to answer your question if you share parts of your code and some comments on where you got stuck when implementing this.

Comment: Will update more details soon on the question. I need to rephrase the question and adjust my answer to reflect what is the exact change I did. For now if you follow thru the code, possibly cut and paste the code into 'stackblitz.com' it will work and you can see the output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code, all I did is I took the example from the above Kendo Grid auto generated columns and changed it  - example provided by: Udhaya Kannan

```
app.component.ts
-----------------

import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { sampleProducts } from "./products";
import { Product } from "./product.model";
import { distinct } from "@progress/kendo-data-query";

interface ColumnSetting {
  field: string;
  title: string;
  format?: string;
  type: "text" | "numeric" | "boolean" | "date";
}

interface GroupColumnSetting {
  title: string;
  supplierId: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <kendo-grid
      [kendoGridBinding]="gridData"
      [filterable]="true"
      scrollable="none"
    >
      <kendo-grid-column
        field="ProgramCode"
        title="Main Program Code"
      ></kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column-group
        [headerStyle]="{ 'text-align': 'center' }"
        *ngFor="let groupColumn of groupColumns"
        title="{{ groupColumn.title }}"
        [locked]="false"
      >
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product-ID">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            {{ getProductID(dataItem.ProductID, groupColumn.supplierId) }}
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="SupplierID" title="Supplier-ID">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            {{ getSupplierID(dataItem.ProductID, groupColumn.supplierId) }}
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product-Name">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            {{ getProductName(dataItem.ProductID, groupColumn.supplierId) }}
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid-column-group>
    </kendo-grid>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public gridData: any[] = distinct(sampleProducts, "ProgramCode");
  public arrayResult: Product[] = sampleProducts;

  public isAssociatedIds(
    supplierID: number,
    groupColumnSupplierID: number
  ): boolean {
    return supplierID == groupColumnSupplierID;
  }

  public getProductName(productID: number, supplierID: number): string {
    const localProduct = this.arrayResult.find(
      x => x.ProductID == productID && x.SupplierID == supplierID
    );

    return localProduct.ProductName;
  }

  public getProductID(productID: number, supplierID: number): number {
    const localProduct = this.arrayResult.find(
      x => x.ProductID == productID && x.SupplierID == supplierID
    );

    return localProduct.ProductID;
  }

  public getSupplierID(productID: number, supplierID: number): number {
    const localProduct = this.arrayResult.find(
      x => x.ProductID == productID && x.SupplierID == supplierID
    );

    return localProduct.SupplierID;
  }

  public groupColumns: GroupColumnSetting[] = [
    {
      title: "Supplier Test 1",
      supplierId: 1
    },
    {
      title: "Supplier Test 2",
      supplierId: 2
    }
  ];

  public columns: ColumnSetting[] = [
    {
      field: "ProductName",
      title: "Product Name",
      type: "text"
    },
    {
      field: "UnitPrice",
      format: "{0:c}",
      title: "Unit Price",
      type: "numeric"
    },
    {
      field: "FirstOrderedOn",
      format: "{0:d}",
      title: "First Ordered",
      type: "date"
    }
  ];
}
```

```
product.model.ts
----------------
export class Product 
 {
    ProductID: number;
    ProductName: string;
    SupplierID: number;
    ProgramCode: string;
    CategoryID: number;
    QuantityPerUnit: string;
    UnitPrice: number;
    UnitsInStock: number;
    UnitsOnOrder: number;
    ReorderLevel: number;
    Discontinued: boolean;
    Category: Category;
    FirstOrderedOn: Date;
  }

  export class Category {
    CategoryID: number;
    CategoryName: string;
    Description: string;
  }
```

```
products.ts
-----------

export const sampleProducts = [
  {
    ProductID: 1,
    ProductName: "Chai",
    SupplierID: 1,
    ProgramCode: "ABC",
    CategoryID: 1,
    QuantityPerUnit: "10 boxes x 20 bags",
    UnitPrice: 18,
    UnitsInStock: 39,
    UnitsOnOrder: 0,
    ReorderLevel: 10,
    Discontinued: false,
    Category: {
      CategoryID: 1,
      CategoryName: "Beverages",
      Description: "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    },
    FirstOrderedOn: new Date(1996, 8, 20)
  },
  {
    ProductID: 2,
    ProductName: "Chang",
    SupplierID: 1,
    ProgramCode: "XYZ",
    CategoryID: 1,
    QuantityPerUnit: "24 - 12 oz bottles",
    UnitPrice: 19,
    UnitsInStock: 17,
    UnitsOnOrder: 40,
    ReorderLevel: 25,
    Discontinued: false,
    Category: {
      CategoryID: 1,
      CategoryName: "Beverages",
      Description: "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    },
    FirstOrderedOn: new Date(1996, 7, 12)
  },
  {
    ProductID: 3,
    ProductName: "Aniseed Syrup",
    SupplierID: 1,
    ProgramCode: "TET",
    CategoryID: 2,
    QuantityPerUnit: "12 - 550 ml bottles",
    UnitPrice: 10,
    UnitsInStock: 13,
    UnitsOnOrder: 70,
    ReorderLevel: 25,
    Discontinued: false,
    Category: {
      CategoryID: 2,
      CategoryName: "Condiments",
      Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    },
    FirstOrderedOn: new Date(1996, 8, 26)
  },
  {
    ProductID: 4,
    ProductName: "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",
    SupplierID: 1,
    ProgramCode: "NAM",
    CategoryID: 2,
    QuantityPerUnit: "48 - 6 oz jars",
    UnitPrice: 22,
    UnitsInStock: 53,
    UnitsOnOrder: 0,
    ReorderLevel: 0,
    Discontinued: false,
    Category: {
      CategoryID: 2,
      CategoryName: "Condiments",
      Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    },
    FirstOrderedOn: new Date(1996, 9, 19)
  },
  {
    ProductID: 5,
    ProductName: "Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix",
    SupplierID: 1,
    ProgramCode: "GMO",
    CategoryID: 2,
    QuantityPerUnit: "36 boxes",
    UnitPrice: 21.35,
    UnitsInStock: 0,
    UnitsOnOrder: 0,
    ReorderLevel: 0,
    Discontinued: true,
    Category: {
      CategoryID: 2,
      CategoryName: "Condiments",
      Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    },
    FirstOrderedOn: new Date(1996, 7, 17)
  },
  {
    ProductID: 1,
    ProductName: "Chai 2",
    SupplierID: 2,
    ProgramCode: "ABC",
    CategoryID: 1,
    QuantityPerUnit: "10 boxes x 20 bags",
    UnitPrice: 18,
    UnitsInStock: 39,
    UnitsOnOrder: 0,
    ReorderLevel: 10,
    Discontinued: false,
    Category: {
      CategoryID: 1,
      CategoryName: "Beverages",
      Description: "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    },
    FirstOrderedOn: new Date(1996, 8, 20)
  },
  {
    ProductID: 2,
    ProductName: "Chang 2",
    SupplierID: 2,
    ProgramCode: "XYZ",
    CategoryID: 1,
    QuantityPerUnit: "24 - 12 oz bottles",
    UnitPrice: 19,
    UnitsInStock: 17,
    UnitsOnOrder: 40,
    ReorderLevel: 25,
    Discontinued: false,
    Category: {
      CategoryID: 1,
      CategoryName: "Beverages",
      Description: "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    },
    FirstOrderedOn: new Date(1996, 7, 12)
  },
  {
    ProductID: 3,
    ProductName: "Aniseed Syrup 2",
    SupplierID: 2,
    ProgramCode: "TET",
    CategoryID: 2,
    QuantityPerUnit: "12 - 550 ml bottles",
    UnitPrice: 10,
    UnitsInStock: 13,
    UnitsOnOrder: 70,
    ReorderLevel: 25,
    Discontinued: false,
    Category: {
      CategoryID: 2,
      CategoryName: "Condiments",
      Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    },
    FirstOrderedOn: new Date(1996, 8, 26)
  },
  {
    ProductID: 4,
    ProductName: "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning 2",
    SupplierID: 2,
    ProgramCode: "NAM",
    CategoryID: 2,
    QuantityPerUnit: "48 - 6 oz jars",
    UnitPrice: 22,
    UnitsInStock: 53,
    UnitsOnOrder: 0,
    ReorderLevel: 0,
    Discontinued: false,
    Category: {
      CategoryID: 2,
      CategoryName: "Condiments",
      Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    },
    FirstOrderedOn: new Date(1996, 9, 19)
  },
  {
    ProductID: 5,
    ProductName: "Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix 2",
    SupplierID: 2,
    ProgramCode: "GMO",
    CategoryID: 2,
    QuantityPerUnit: "36 boxes",
    UnitPrice: 21.35,
    UnitsInStock: 0,
    UnitsOnOrder: 0,
    ReorderLevel: 0,
    Discontinued: true,
    Category: {
      CategoryID: 2,
      CategoryName: "Condiments",
      Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    },
    FirstOrderedOn: new Date(1996, 7, 17)
  }
];
```

```
app.module.ts
-------------
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, GridModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```